# Remove similar looking string from a list in Python

Tags: python, list

I have a list in python where I want to remove elements that may already be present concatenated with another element.

**Example 1:**

```
list1 = ['data', 'entry', 'data entry']

output = ['data entry']
```

Expectation is to remove 'data' and 'entry' when data entry is already present.

**Example 2:**

```
list1 = ['dining table', 'table', 'dining']

output = ['dining table']
```

Comment: Please post you work and progress of what you have tried so far.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You should check the items which can be split based on space delimiter and the element should be removed if any parts of splited string presents in the original list.

I have written an example code with many comments and tests.

**Code:**

```
list1 = ["data", "entry", "data entry"]
list2 = ["dining table", "table", "dining"]
list3 = ["very fast car", "car", "bird", "fast"]


def my_func(my_list):
    for x in my_list:  # Iter through the getting list
        if " " not in x:  # Check if single element
            continue  # Get the nex element if single element
        for y in x.split(" "):  # Split the element on space delimiter
            if y in my_list:  # If the part of element is in the getting list
                my_list.remove(y)  # Remove the existing single element from list.


my_func(list1)
my_func(list2)
my_func(list3)

print(list1)
print(list2)
print(list3)
```

**Output:**

```
>>> python3 test.py
['data entry']
['dining table']
['very fast car', 'bird']
```

**EDIT:**

If you want to checking the all combination of splited string you can use the `itertools` module (`chain`, `combinations`).

With this solution:

Input: `["very fast car", "car", "bird", "fast", "very fast", "very car"]`

Output: `["very fast car", "bird"]`

It means the `"very fast"` and `"very car"` elements also will be removed because these are combinations of `"very fast car"` element parts.

**Code:**

```
from itertools import chain, combinations

list1 = ["data", "entry", "data entry"]
list2 = ["dining table", "table", "dining"]
list3 = ["very fast car", "car", "bird", "fast"]
list4 = ["very fast car", "car", "bird", "fast", "very fast", "very car"]


def powerset(iterable):
    s = list(iterable)  # allows duplicate elements
    return chain.from_iterable(combinations(s, r) for r in range(len(s)+1))  # Return the all combinations


def my_func(my_list):
    for x in my_list:  # Iter through the getting list
        if " " not in x:  # Check if single element
            continue  # Get the nex element if single element
        for combo in powerset(x.split(" ")):  # Iterate through the all combination
            related_string = " ".join(combo)  # Create space separated strings from list elements
            if related_string == x:  # Skip the removing if the created string is same as the tested element
                continue
            if related_string in my_list:  # If the part of element is in the getting list
                my_list.remove(related_string)  # Remove the existing single element from list.


my_func(list1)
my_func(list2)
my_func(list3)
my_func(list4)

print(list1)
print(list2)
print(list3)
print(list4)
```

**Output:**

```
>>> python3 test.py
['data entry']
['dining table']
['very fast car', 'bird']
['very fast car', 'bird']
```

Comment: `["very fast car", "car", "bird", "fast", "very fast"]` results in `['very fast car', 'bird', 'very fast']`

Comment: @ack, you are right. I have added a solution to my answer which checking the combinations of multi-word elements.